# How to add a style when i get an external text?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I am creating a blog and my question is if it is possible to add a style to a text that I am calling from my DB For example, I can add a space each time `\n` reads in the text and thus separate the paragraphs.

```
const text =
'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.\n Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s. \n when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.';

{text.split('\n\n').map(paragraph => (
                        <Typography
                            mt={2}
                            fontSize='1.125rem'
                            component='p'
                            color='text.secondary'
                            style={{
                                wordWrap: 'break-word',
                                hyphens: 'auto',
                            }}
                        >
                            {paragraph
                                .split('\n')
                                .reduce((total, line) => [
                                    total,
                                    <br />,
                                    <br />,
                                    line,
                                ])}
                        </Typography>
                    ))}
```

I can create the paragraphs with that code, but here is my question: every time I detect a `<span> text </span>`, how can I add a style to the span to make it stand out from the text.

Or at least how can I style linear text received from a database?

Comment: This needs more context to be answered. I assume you need to style span separately. You can not distinguish it from the other elements.

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i want

Comment: What about using Regex to match all the span tags? `<span\s*.*>\s*.*<\/span>`